# Strange Error on Parent relationships with apex:outputText - Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.Name'

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a Child object Commercial_Terms_ED_Approval__c with a master detail relationship to it's parent Commercial_Terms__c. However my visualforce pageBlockTable is having issues pulling in parent fields.

The controller compiles fine without errors, but I get the following error when trying to save either of the commented binded parent fields: {!ct.Commercial_Terms__r.Name} {!ct.Commercial_Terms__r.Related_Opportunity__c}. I feel like this is something silly I am overlooking - I've done this dozens of times...

Note: the query comes back with records without issue in debug statements - the problem appears to lie within the visualforce mark-up.

Controller:

```
    public class edCTApprovalQueueController {

    public List<Commercial_Terms_ED_Approval__c> ctList {get;set;}

    public edCTApprovalQueueController() {

        ctList = [SELECT id, Commercial_Terms__c, Commercial_Terms__r.Name, Original_Proposal_Manager__r.Name, CreatedBy.Name, Approver__c, name, Commercial_Terms__r.Related_Opportunity__c from Commercial_Terms_ED_Approval__c WHERE Escalated_Approval__c = true AND Commercial_Terms__r.Related_Opportunity__c != null];
    }

    public PageReference cancel(){
        PageReference pageRef = ApexPages.CurrentPage();
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;
    }

    public PageReference quickApprove(){
        return null;
    }

}
```

Visualforce:

```
    <apex:page controller="edCTApprovalQueueController" showHeader="true" sidebar="true">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Unassigned Discount Approvals">  

        <apex:pageBlockTable id="pageblocktableid" value="{!ctList}" var="ct">
            <apex:column headerValue="CT Approval Request">
                <a href="/{!ct.id}">{!ct.name}</a>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Approver">
                <apex:outputfield value="{!ct.Approver__c}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Original Proposal Manager">
                <apex:outputfield value="{!ct.Original_Proposal_Manager__r.Name}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Commercial Terms Id">
                <apex:outputText value="{!ct.Commercial_Terms__c}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Commercial Terms Name">
                <!--apex:outputText value="{!ct.Commercial_Terms__r.Name}"/--> <!--Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.Name'-->
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Opportunity Id">
            <!--apex:outputText value="{!ct.Commercial_Terms__r.Related_Opportunity__c}"/--> <!--Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.Name'-->
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs when you try to access a list as a scalar (a single value). This suggests that you have a lookup field that creates a relationship named `Commerical_Terms__r`, as well as a lookup field named `Commercial_Terms__c` (which would also be referenced as `Commercial_Terms__r` to navigate to the parent). This causes some weird behavior in certain places. Try the following query in the Developer Console:

```
SELECT Commercial_Terms__r.Name,
    (SELECT Name FROM Commercial_Terms__r) 
from Commercial_Terms_ED_Approval__c
```

If you have created this condition, you should get the following error:

```
duplicate field selected: Commercial_Terms__r
```

If you have this condition, you will need to rename either the lookup field or the relationship in order to fix this problem in your Visualforce code. This will involve refactoring any related metadata, such as triggers, classes, components, etc. You'll need to figure out which solution would cause the minimum amount of fuss.

Comment: Wow genius suggestion as always Fox. I wouldn’t have considered that. I’ll try that and let you know how it goes. #sfdcFoxIsAwesome